# Apache Lucene: How to get the first matching substring from a Document

Tags: java, lucene

I could not find any info on the web and stackoverflow on how to get the first matching character subsequence from a Lucene Document.

ATM i'm using this logic to retrieve results from Lucene:

```
        Document doc=searcher.doc(hit.doc);
        String text=doc.get("text");
        if (text.length() > 80){
            text=text.substring(0,80);
        }
        results.add(new SearchResult(doc.get("url"), doc.get("title"), text));
```

As you can see this just takes the first 80 chars of the searched text and wraps it together with some other data into a SearchResult object.

Is it somehow possible to retrieve the first or even highest scoring subsequence of the text which actually contains any searchterms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [Lucene Highlighter](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/contrib-highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/package-summary.html). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82151/is-there-a-fast-accurate-highlighter-for-lucene) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409870/using-hit-highlighter-in-lucene) you can find some more info on it.

Comment: Also note that there are several Highlighter implementations for both Lucene 2.x and Lucene 3.0. Take the one that fits your task better.

Answer (score 1):

It is called [hit highlighter](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_1/api/contrib-highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/package-summary.html). This is probably a duplicate of [another highlighter question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208839/hit-highlighting-in-lucene)